# How to search fast in list with 40 milions words?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

How to search fast in list which contains 40 millions words?

I need find words which contains at least 4 letters which I specified before the proceed.

Example: in list there are few words:

```
dogging
dopping
baobabisaneviltree
```

My specific letters in string format 'odxxini'. I need find any words containing any (4+) chars from my string.

Result:

```
dopping
dogging
```

(because, both words contains 'o' 'd' 'i' 'n')
I hope i explained well. Sorry for english. Please correct the mistakes.

If anyone has any knowledge about that problem, i will be glad to hear him. :)

I wrote so far (because it's the beginning.. ) this code:

```
private void seeksearcher()
        {
            double counter = 0, k=0;
            double licznik = (double)listwords.Capacity;

            char[] letterarray = stringletters.ToCharArray();
            foreach(String word in listwords)
            {

                for(int i=0;i<letterarray.Length;i++)
                    if(word.Contains(letterarray[i]))
                        counter++;
                if(counter > 4)
                    textBox2.Text+=word + Environment.NewLine;

            }
        }
```

I am pretty sure that complexity is now n*7n, its ugly big :(

Comment: creating (and using) an index over your dictionary will speed your searches

Comment: Would the string "iixx" be a match to the example? That is, does including "x" twice mean that two "x"s in the sought string would count as two matching letters?

Comment: I believe your complexity is more `n * m`, where `n` is the length of the list and `m` is the length of the search string.

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge if i have two xx in my specific string (of course that string i cut to char array) it means that the words "can" have two x'es however i would like find words which are containing as much as it can letters from my specific string. Each letter which was used wont be used anymore in that word.

Comment: @Michal, no, I mean it would be like 40,000,000 * 8, using hypothetical lengths of your word list and search string. Actually, you know what, it's more `n * m * k`, length of list * length of word * length of search string. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Anthony i understand you, the answer before was wrong of corse so i deleted. whit that complexity i would wait about 3333 year :) or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, clearly no solution is faster than the size of the solution set.  If you happen to have a search string that matches *every* word in the lexicon then enumerating the solution set requires enumerating the lexicon.

Let's suppose the size of every solution set is very small compared to the size of the lexicon.

Let's also suppose that the size of every entry in the lexicon is short; you don't have any ten-thousand letter words in there or something silly like that.

Given those two constraints, the big question is *do you require sublinear search time?*

Linear time algorithms are straightforward. For example:

- sort the characters of every lexicon word into alphabetical order.
- sort the characters of the query into alphabetical order
- do a sequence comparison of sorted query against every word of the sorted lexicon.

That is, suppose you have the lexicon

```
STOPPING
POTSHARD
OPTING
DECORATE
```

and the query `TOPSXZ`.  Sort the query by character: `OPSTXZ`.  Now go through the lexicon, sorting it by character:

```
STOPPING --> GINOPPST
POTSHARD --> ADHOPRST
OPTING   --> GINOPT
DECORATE --> ACDEEORT
```

And now it is easy to tell if you have four or more matches; you just run the Longest Common Subsequence algorithm on `OPSTXZ` and `GINOPPST` and discover that the longest common subsequence is `OPST`, which is four letters, so it matches. The longest common subsequence of `OPSTXZ` and `ADHOPRST` is also `OPST`, so it maches. The longest common subsequence of `OPSTXY` and `GINOPT` is `OPT`, which is only three, and the longest common subsequence of `OPSTXY` and `ACDEEORT` is `OT`, which is only two.

Assuming the words are all short, we know that the Longest Common Subsequence problem and the Sort A Bunch of Characters problem can be solved quickly. You just have to do that 40 million times and you're done.

Now, if you want a *sublinear* solution, where you eliminate a bunch of those 40 million lexicon words from consideration early, that's going to be harder. Do you require a sublinear solution?

Comment: Harder, but more interesting!  :D

Answer (score 2):

Can you index the words ahead of time?  I would start by indexing the word list creating a sorted list of words for each character:

```
a: baobabisaneviltree
b: baobabisaneviltree
c: 
d: dogging, dopping
e: etc
```

Then for each letter in the input string I would gather the words that matched, put them in a dictionary, and increment the number of times each word was found.

```
dogging: 4
dopping: 4
dapper: 1
```

Then I would walk through the dictionary looking for numbers greater than 4.

If you can't index then your solution is about as good as you can get.  You necessarily need to look at each letter in each word (O(n*m)) to see if a given letter appears in a word then you need to check for each letter.  One issue with your solution is that you will add the word to the text box multiple times, you may want to make it `if(counter == 4)`.

---

Code fun (untested):

```
// With 40 million words this can use a lot of space.  You would probably
// want to create the index on disk and maybe the intermediate processing
// as well.
var index = wordList.SelectMany(word => word.ToCharArray(), 
                                (word, character) => 
                                  new { word, character})
                    .ToLookup(x => x.character, x => x.word);
var result = letterArray.Distinct()
                        .SelectMany(c => index[c])
                        .GroupBy(word => word)
                        .Where(word => word.Count() > 4)
                        .Select(word => word.Key);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to tackle this problem, but off the top of my head you would likely have to use some kind of index system. These indexes will take up as much, and probably significantly more memory than the words themselves.

For example, you might have pointers to all words that contain the letter d, then pointers to all words that contain the letter o.  Etc..  then you get a much smaller list that you can more easily search by finding the intersection of your letters (words that have all your required letters in them).

Of course this just shuffles the work around, making it require a great deal of processing up front rather than at search time.

Comment: edit: what about start separate thread on each letter index ?

Comment: Certainly, you can do multi-threaded processing.  You might look into using the Parlell extensions for that.